# Wordpress upload images fails – post-processing error

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload

Since about a week back, I’ve started to experience failures in uploading images using the “upload files” option in “Add media”. When it fails, the upload eventually times out and I get the following error message:

Post-processing of the image likely failed because the server is busy or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.

The images are relatively small. 900x500px and about 80kb in size, so the message is probably a generic one. Strangely, when I go back later to check the media page, the images have been uploaded although it gave me that error message and was stuck loading.

I don't believe it's a server issue because on my other sites which use the same theme and are on the same server, I don't have this issue.

I tried deactivating one plugin at a time but that didn’t help. Later I noticed that if I upload the original image (400 kb) it uploads with no issue. If I compress it in Photoshop (80kb) as I have always done in the past without any problems, then it gives me the error.

This is so odd. Compressing in Photoshop by setting quality to 50% (or lower) suddenly now fails upload (but work only a week ago). However, setting quality between 51-100% works fine when uploading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should enable WordPress to debug log, and/or check about your webserver (apache/Nginx) and PHP error logs. You can also test to open your console while uploading and see if there are some details in the HTTP response.

Comment: My host cloned the site and on the cloned version this problem disappears. My host suspects Cloudflare to be the issue. I set Cloudlfare to development mode, but problem still persists. I even changed the nameservers but no good, although not sure I gave it enough time for it to propagate.

Comment: The issue was indeed Cloudflare. Just for the record.